# How to keep iTunes video window always on top

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion

How do I keep the video window above all the other windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the answer on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47452/how-to-make-itunes-video-window-float-on-topT):

"There is an option under Preferences -> Advanced Preferences, under the separator saying 'Keep movie window on top of all other windows'. "

Comment: Thank you. Why do they bury this option? grrr...